# Is there a command or shortcut for "remove this qualification" off quick fix in visual studio (C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

Is there any automatic or mouse free way to remove "this" keyword of code in the current document in visual studio (except re-sharper)?

Comment: Which keyword are you talking about?

Comment: @rob "this"  keyword I fixed the question

Comment: `Ctrl + .`, then right arrow key twice, enter twice (VS2015)

Comment: What is the problem with re-sharper?

Comment: @ Mathias I meant some active commands even when you are not at the line that needs the fix you can run, like command for "Remove and Sort Usings"

Comment: @fox no problem with ReSharper though I want something light wait and free

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544 Hope this helps

Comment: I think that all of them are designed to get rid of the unused code recognized by VS and not the specific keywords because some of them are crucial in the code and VS doesn't allow to delete user defined keyword through whole code by just one click. I wanted to do that too when I first upgraded my VS. I realized that it's not that important.